# Symbols for DAX from Alpha Vantage

Tags: programming, exchange

I found the website https://www.alphavantage.co as an alternative for yahoo finance stock API.

I am interested in the top 30 DAX symbols, but I seem to cannot find them on Alpha Vantage. Is there a list of supported stock exchange markets and symbols, where I can look for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use BMV instead of BMW (I don't know Alpha Vantage reasons for it)

Playing a little bit it looks the symbol for the index is just DAX:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=DAX&interval=1min&apikey=MYAPIKEY
```

Which retrives this answer:

```
"1. Information": "Intraday (1min) prices and volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "DAX",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-02-23 15:13:00",
    "4. Interval": "1min",
    "5. Output Size": "Compact",
    "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
```

So if you try any of the stocks belonging to the DAX you´ll see if they are available on Alpha Vantage. Just replace XXSYMBOLXX with the one you are interested and use your API KEY instead of MYAPIKEY:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=XXSYMBOLXX&interval=1min&apikey=MYAPIKEY
```

Comment: When I call the DAX with `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=DAX&interval=1min&outputsize=full&datatype=csv&apikey=xxx` I get data, however if I call `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=BMW&interval=1min&outputsize=full&datatype=csv&apikey=xxx` I get the message "Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY." which I figured that they don't support that symbol (in this case `BMW`)

Comment: If I use this:   https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=BMV&interval=1min&apikey=DEMO   I have data:   {
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (1min) prices and volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "BMV",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-02-23 11:01:00",
        "4. Interval": "1min",
        "5. Output Size": "Compact",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (1min)": {
        "2018-02-23 11:01:00": {
            "1. open": "2.8890",
            "2. high": "2.8890",    Click my link in this comment and you see.

Comment: This is also working:   https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&outputsize=full&symbol=BMV&DATATYPE=csv&interval=1min&apikey=DEMO

Comment: Try BMV instead of BMW  (Don't ask me why... we need to ask alpha avantage  :)

Comment: SAP is working too:  https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=sap&DATATYPE=csv&outputsize=full&interval=1min&apikey=DEMO

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful. However I'm still missing about half the symbols, I used to fetch. Icannot find some like: PSM (Prosiebensat1)
TKA (ThyssenKrupp)
FME (Fresenius)
RWE
EOAN (E.ON)
FRE (Fresenius)
DAI (Daimler)
VNA (Vonovia)
LHA (Lufthansa)
DBK (Deutsche Bank)
LIN (Linde)

Comment: PSM: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=PSM&interval=1min&apikey=DEMO

Comment: VNA: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=VNA&interval=1min&apikey=DEMO

Comment: But I think Alpha Vantage should give or show in the web a list of the available symbols. It´s not understandable we have to guess... :(    and you are spending so many time on this.

Comment: DBK: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=DBK&interval=1min&apikey=DEMO

Comment: FRE: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=FRE&interval=1min&apikey=DEMO

Comment: DAI: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=DAI&interval=1min&apikey=DEMO

Comment: LHA: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=LHA&interval=1min&apikey=DEMO

Comment: I hope this helps!!!  Good luck!!!. Let me know if I could help with anything else.

Comment: Wow, I tested all of them yesterday and always got "Invalid API call. Please retry or visit the documentation (https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/) for TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY." as a return. After calling the same URL twice or three times, it works. Any idea why this is?

Comment: If you click on my links directly, is it still returning the error?

Comment: only sometimes. After a couple of retries they work

Comment: If that´s the result then I think is not your code´s "fault", it looks a Alpha Vantage issue

Answer (score 3):

Firstly some background:

DAX is a German stock market index for blue chip companies.  It has 30 components.

AlphaVantage does not officially support European exchanges.

So, you cannot query AlphaVantage for the 30 DAX stocks at all, although some might have ADRs listed in USA, it won't represent the actual European trading at all.

In addition they don't actually respond to questions on their forums about coverage:
https://www.alpha-vantage.community/post/ukeuropean-stock-prices-9676329

Some are exposed, but others are not.  I suspect AlphaVantage is just scraping its data from somewhere undisclosed and does not even have a true understanding of international trading, currencies, etc.

Answer (score 3):

AlphaVantage returns all the DAX (and FTSE, CAC, MIB etc.) components fine, you just have to add the appropriate suffix i.e. `BMW.FRK` (BMW) and `AIR.PAR` (Airbus).

Best way to use it is to install the free Excel/Google Sheets add-on and then use the `=AVSearchEquitySymbol(search string)` function.

I do all my AlphaVantage testing on Google Sheets, before writing code.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol for the DAX is ^GDAXI , in case you came here via Google.
https://www.alpha-vantage.community/post/world-indexes-9627480

Answer (score 0):

To find prices for FTSE stocks on Alpha Vantage you stick the `.LON` suffix on the symbol:

e.g.

```
curl https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=AZN.LON&apikey=APIKEY
```